# Howto select array elements in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an array myvideos which contained few elements, say, "Intel","NVIDIA",and "RANDON", how to use myvideos as selector elements? As shown below, I'm able to get one element of myvideos.
Any ideas? Thank you!

```
oVideos=$Videos
Videos="Please select a video card: "
select myvideo in "$myvideos"
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the title of your question into Google? Please add what code you've tried so far.

Comment: please edit your code to include a definition for `$myvideos`. Good luck.

Comment: Change "RANDON" to "RADEON", that should fix it.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, but I think you are looking for `select myvideo in ${myvideos[@]}`

Comment: I think a loop is what you're looking for.

Comment: How are you setting `myvideos`? My guess is you don't actually have an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `select`:

```
#! /bin/bash

MyVideos=("INTEL" "NVIDIA" "RANDONONNJSDHF")
PS3="Please select a video card: "
select myvideo in ${MyVideos[@]}
do
    echo "$myvideo selected"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much dtmilano. Thank you everybody! Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you shed some light:

```
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ MyVideos=("INTEL" "NVIDIA" "RANDONONNJSDHF")
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ 
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ for entry in "${MyVideos[@]}"; do echo $entry; done;
INTEL
NVIDIA
RANDONONNJSDHF
[aesteban@localhost ~]$
```

Good luck!!